# Schematics RF transmitter

Tags: rf, pcb-design, circuit-design, transmitter, pcb-antenna

I'm attaching a schematic of an RF transmitter made by [Synoxo.](http://www.synoxo.com/) Chip is the [SYN115.](https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/33/SYN113-SYN115-datasheet-version-1-1-.0.pdf) The schematic is found in the datasheet.

I do not understand why L3 which is the PCB antenna (pointed with the red arrow) is connected on both ends. As far as I know, antennas are connected on one end on a PCB and the other end is not connected anywhere. Also why there is no value to L3?

Also what is the black arrow (pointed with my blue line?)

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Site policy to to credit the work of others when posted on this site. Please edit your post to give credit to the owner of the schematic you've posted.

Comment: how to edit it? its a schematic made by Synoxo

Comment: @ChrisT Did you draw the schematic yourself? If so, then you should know what the symbol means. If not, **provide a link or citation** to the original source...a web page or a document. =

Comment: I already said its made by Synoxo!

Comment: Hit the edit link below your question ...

Answer (score 1):

The black arrow just means that the antenna/coil has an adjustable tap, that allows it's performance to be adjusted.  It shorts out part of the antenna, thus changing it's electrical length.

**EDIT 1 - Added IEEE symbol for adjustable inductor**

From IEEE Std 315, here's the symbol for an adjustable inductor:

[image]

Comment: No, that would be a shorted turn - very lossy. I suspect the connection from GND to tap IS the antenna ( a loop)  : tapped inductor L3 is an autotransformer, providing impedance matching for best efficiency between the TX output and the loop antenna.

Answer (score 1):

> why there is no value to L3?

L3 (or at least the loop part) is printed on the PCB (as indicated on the schematic) hence isn't a lumped component you need to provide. The antenna is shown (somewhat vaguely) on the PCB diagram in section 15 of the datasheet you took the schematic from.

It would have been helpful if you had provided a direct link to the datasheet you are using with your original question rather than adding a bit more information for each comment/answer received.

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose a value for L3.  It is a specifically shaped trace on your PCB.

The circuit you gave is a "typical application," but isn't a full design.

Later in the datasheet, the manufacturer shows the circuit and layout for a demo board they produce using the SYN115.

Here's the circuit:

[image]

Here's the layout:

[image]

L5 is the antenna in the schematic, and L5 is that thick trace along top half of the layout on the right (the top layer.)

The parts list also says that L5 is the antenna and that is part of the PCB:

[image]

It is formed and dimensioned to be resonant at the transmitter operating frequency of the transmitter.

There are no details given for the dimensions of L5.

You have a few options:

1. Contact the manufacturer and ask for more details.
2. Place a jack for an antenna connector and use a normal antenna.
3. "Eyeball" the dimensions of the example antenna and hope for the best.

If you work for a company that will be making a whole bunch of these things, then you should go with option 1.  Options 2 and 3 are really only "usable" if you are doing a one off for a hobby project.

---

Another option would be to study antenna design, and design your own loop antenna and matching network.

---

If you'd like to install a jack and connect a regular antenna to the chip, then have a look at Figure 2 from the datasheet.  That's a test circuit followed by a PCB layout.  It includes a circuit for connecting a 50 ohm antenna jack.

[image]

---

As a final option, you can just ignore matching and antenna design and just do what all the manufacturers do that make and sell the cheap SYN115 modules on AliExpress:  Include an eyelet where the antenna should be (the antenna jack in Figure 2) and just hang a random piece of wire on it as an antenna.

Most of the projects you'll find on the internet that use these modules don't even bother putting an antenna wire on the module.  They just assume (as you seem to) that the modules have an antenna on board.

Comment: Regarding L5, you said to place a jack for an antenna Connector. But place it where? On the gnd? Or on the right of L4? Because L5 seems to have 2 "jacks"

Comment: Also that schematic seems too big. I want to replicate syn115 transmitter(google it) pcb to embed it on my board. The first schematic seems closer to that transmittet

Comment: Do you mean any one of the dozens of projects google finds, or do you mean the module.  Google returns different results for everybody, and I have no idea what it turns up for you.  Why don't you just link to it instead of telling me to google for something to help you?

Comment: All the modules I found have an eyelet where you should attach an antenna.  It's pretty much just hang a wire in it and hope it works.  They aren't properly matched to the transmitter.  It's all just "meh, it'll work some how."

Comment: At the bottom is the tranmitter https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1BcpAau38SeJjSZFPq6A_vFXab.jpg

Comment: But where shall I make the hole to hang the wire? Does it have to be on the GND? or it doesn't matter? Also do you agree that those modules seem to be like the first schematic that I Posted?

Comment: The modules are **not** like the first schematic you posted.  They are more like Figure 2 from the datasheet.  Figure 2 also shows you where the antenna should be connected.

Comment: Could you make a schematic and pcb design for me like the one on the link I provided? If yes, how much would it cost. BTW I only thought its the first schematic because of the numbers of the components(capacitors etc)

Comment: Just for fun, I had the price for a 15mm by 12mm 2 sided PCB estimated.  If I order 200 of them, they'll cost about 55 cents each.  That's just having the board made - no parts placed.  You'd have to add in the cost of parts and assembly.

Comment: I think if you do the design I can order the prototypes + assembly from the internet and receive everything by dhl quickly. Minimum is like 5 boards. Total like 60usd with the parts. Just prototypes.. How much would you like for the design etc?

Comment: I didn't say I'd do it.  I just had a look at the cost because I was curious.  I don't know why you want to make your own when the things are cheap as dirt.

Comment: Completed modules are available on Aliexpress for 40 cents each.

Comment: I want to embed them on my board..

Comment: Cheapest to just use a pin header and attach a purchased module to your own PCB.  Also easiest.

Comment: But I need one pcb instead of using modules.